# Huge Magento database

Tags: magento-1.8, product, performance

I have a magento site with a huge database (~9G) with empty log tables on MySQL and the site is getting a little bit slower with the databases getting larger. Is magento designed to support a databases this large with ~200K products ? If not what are the alternatives besides deleting products ?

I know this is a vague question  but i just want some informed opinions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please sort your mysql tables and post here the biggest up to 10 rows. how many databases/shops you have on this server? also it goot to know your mysqltuner.pl output, also server specs

Comment: Make sure you dont have duplicate product names, this could be the source of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the issue is the database? It could of course also be an issue with bad scripts.

Comment: Strangely after disabling flat tables, loading home page wen from ~ 20 s to ~ 3 seconds ? i think i have read somewhere that flat tables allow to enhance site performance.

Answer (score 1):

Empty report and import/export tables and try again.

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you. Those tables are empty too. My site is no slower than usual, i just want to know if with the database getting bigger and bigger, what changes will i have to make in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Check the size of your url_rewrite table.
If your catalog has a lot of configurables, consisting of not visible individually child items, ensure those child items are not also attached to the categories.

Having all the child invisible items assigned to categories will make your category_products table large. It may also affect indexing and url_rewrite table size. (Can't recall right this moment if invisible items will in fact be indexed)

You only need to assign the configurable itself to any categories.

Comment: No i don't have any configurables products in my website. My core_url_rewrite table is 2.3 G large with ~ 3 millions rows, is it normal ?

Comment: Sounds a bit big....but it could very well be in relation to your catalog size. Google a bit about magento url rewrite issues. It could be you have run into some known issues. Also get newrelic hooked in. That way you can easily pin point any issues.